# Linux (Mint 17.1) Video card's (R9 270x) sound is claimed by pci stub but the GPU isn't

Tags: linux, graphics-card, virtualization, linux-kvm

So I'm trying to setup a gaming VM with on Linux Mint via KVM and VFIO. I've added the ID's of both the sound and the actual GPU but only the sound is getting claimed by stub. When I run dmesg | grep pci-stub this is the output:

[    3.622478] pci-stub: add 1002:AAB0 sub=FFFFFFFF:FFFFFFFF cls=00000000/00000000

[    3.622490] pci-stub 0000:01:00.1: claimed by stub

[    3.622494] pci-stub: add 1002:6810 sub=FFFFFFFF:FFFFFFFF cls=00000000/00000000

As you can see, only 01:00.1 is claimed by stub (which is the HDMI sound)